# AWS Batch max vCPUs not set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I am new to AWS Batch. I'm executing tasks in AWS Batch and have set the desired vCPU count to 4. If I want to scale, I believe I could adjust the maximum vCPUs. What occurs if I leave this value unset?

Will it scale automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Batch, the "**maximum vCPUs**" value specifies the maximum number of virtual CPUs that can be assigned to your job queue at any given time. When you submit a job to AWS Batch, the "**desired vCPUs**" value **will be used as a goal to assign resources for your work**. If you leave the "**maximum vCPUs**" option unset or set it to a value greater than your intended vCPUs, AWS Batch **will automatically scale up the work queue to meet your target vCPUs**. (*As long as there are available resources in your AWS account's limits.*).

However, if you set the "**maximum vCPUs**" value to a specific number that is lower than your desired vCPUs, AWS Batch **will not be able to allocate more resources beyond that maximum limit**, even if your job queue's desired vCPUs value is set higher. (*This can be useful to prevent overconsumption of resources and to manage costs*).

In summary, **if you leave the "maximum vCPUs" value unset, AWS Batch will scale automatically to fulfill your desired vCPUs, as long as there are available resources within your account limits. If you set a specific value for the maximum vCPUs, AWS Batch will not exceed that limit even if the desired vCPUs are set higher**.

[Read the 'Compute environment parameters' session at the AWS Batch documentaion.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environment_parameters.html)